# Checking emptiness of an element in hpricot

Tags: xml, ruby, parsing, hpricot

Let's say this is the location element:
<.location>blah...<./location>

It can be empty like this:
<.location/>

Is there a way to detect the backslash in the empty element in order to not return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want is the text inside location tags, you can find those easily with the right XPath:

```
doc.search('//location/text()')
```

If, for some reason, you actually need the location element itself, use this:

```
doc.search('//location/text()/..')
```

Comment: big thanks it'll be fixed this way, enough.
in fact, reading the xml from my browser, it actually displays a <.location/>, but hpricot just reopen the tag and enclose the rest of the doc; hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`<location/>` is semantically identical to `<location></location>`, and should be treated as such. To find all empty tags, just skip elements which do not have any child nodes (including text).

Comment: To be consise, this flickr api method is concerned : http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getInfo.html.
When <location>..</location> is empty, hpricot returns it like if it was getting something like <person>...<location><photosurl>...</photourl>etc...</location></person>, in words as if location was enclosing more than it should be.
From a browser you just can see that flickr is returning <location/>.
Very confusing.